# Quote marks - Inverted L / Gamma symbol style?

Tags: xetex, symbols, punctuation, cjk

I'm using XeLaTeX along with the cjk package. I'm trying to recreate quotation marks like the inverted L symbols in the following image:

[image]

**A first attempt.** Here's a MWE after looking at the comments and suggestions from @JoelReyesNoche and @NieldeBeaudrap (thanks for all the help!):

```
\documentclass[UTF8,nofonts]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}

\begin{document}
\title{文件}
\author{我}
\date{2015 年 4 月 25 日}

\maketitle

我说：「您好！」 他答道: 「您好！」

\end{document}
```

> [image]

I would, ideally, like to shorten the vertical part of the quote and lengthen the horizontal part so it looks more like the one in the first image, but it is not clear how.

**A second attempt.** It does seem slightly better when I change the font from `KaiTi` to `AR PL UKai CN`:

> [image]

**Questions.**

1. Am I at the mercy of the font I'm using?
2. Is there a way to get quotation marks closer to those in the original example above?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: [does this help?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/are-there-questions-where-we-can-recognize-that-a-mwe-is-not-necessary) `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}`

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: Nope ... perhaps there are some special packages needed? ;-)

Comment: Not very nice, but better than nothing: `$\lceil$ text $\rfloor$`

Comment: Are you using the cjk package?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I should imagine so! Perhaps the OP would like to know what they are...

Comment: The CJK brackets are Unicode characters U+300C (12300) and U+300D (12301).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I am using the cjk package. Maybe I should've mentioned it in my question.

Comment: What are you using, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...?

Comment: XeLaTeX. I'll make an update to my question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a primitive attempt to achieve outcomes which may be close to what you need. This solution is perhaps suitable for those who wish to achieve square corner quotation marks such as yours, but prefer not to use a typesetting system specialised for Japanese such as pTeX [[PDF documentation](http://ajt.ktug.org/2008/0201okumura.pdf)], or who cannot use a TeX engine specialised to use unicode input (for which the appropriate symbols are `U+300C` and `U+300D` respectively).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalefnt,amsmath}

\newcommand\lrectquote{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{M}%
    \raisebox{0.5\ht0}{%
        \scalefont{0.5}{$\boldsymbol\lceil$}}}
\newcommand\rrectquote{%
    {\scalefont{0.5}{$\boldsymbol\rfloor$}}}
\newcommand\rectquote[1]{%
        \lrectquote#1\rrectquote}

\begin{document}
\rectquote{Rectangular quotation marks}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample image showing simulated Japanese quotes]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the Unicode characters U+231C ("top left corner") and U+231F ("bottom right corner").  Can you type these in using your keyboard?

Comment: The decimal equivalents are 8988 and 8991.  Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi @JoelReyesNoche, I can type the characters but then they show up as empty spaces when I generate the pdf file. I'm using vim so in insert mode, I press `Ctrl-v` then `u` then type 231C and the ⌜ character shows up. Similarly for the ⌟ character except it's 231F. I did the above by replacing the U+300C and U+300D characters in the MWE in my question. Please tell me if I'm doing it wrong, thanks!